# ssh-add : Invalid key length

Tags: macos, ssh

After my Mac upgraded automatically, I try ssh-add fail:

```
>ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /Users/dan/.ssh/id_rsa:
Error loading key "/Users/dan/.ssh/id_rsa": Invalid key length

>ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: which version your macOS is now?

Comment: System Version: macOS 10.13.2 (17C88)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.3.0

Answer (score 25):

As per the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) for OpenSSH 7.6:

> Refuse RSA keys <1024 bits in length and improve reporting for keys
> that do not meet this requirement.

So it's likely that the key you're trying to import is too short (weak).  Your best bet is to generate a new key.

Comment: Is that any method to keep using this key but not new one? It's a lot work to update the key. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan not that I know of.  I'd be surprised if there were.

Comment: To disable the <1024 bits check you may recompile openssh with changing `sshkey.h` file from `#define SSH_RSA_MINIMUM_MODULUS_SIZE 1024` to some other length like `#define SSH_RSA_MINIMUM_MODULUS_SIZE 768`; commit https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/bd636f40911094a39c2920bf87d2ec340533c152 (Upstream-ID: b385e2a7b13b1484792ee681daaf79e1e203df6c https://lists.gt.net/openssh/commits/68358)

Comment: So, is there any "force" option which would allow to update keys on some long not used cloud instances?

Comment: 2019-06-06: I just installed Cygwin+OpenSSH yesterday. Got the usual "server refused our key". Went to Windows Events Viewer, found the error "invalid key length". ALL THE WEBSITES ARE SAYING 1024 IS MINIMUM SIZE BUT IT DIDN'T WORK! So I switched to 2048 key length AND THEN IT WORKED. Hopefully this will work for others!

Comment: Ran into this issue on a debian 10 (buster) container. From the mailing lists, https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2008-August/026830.html, there is no config option; recompile only.

As a quick fix until a new key can be put in place, I added the stretch apt sources and installed openssh-client=1:7.4p1-10+deb9u6.  This is a downgrade and possibly less secure. The long term fix is to use a new key with longer length.

Comment: @KevinNorth is right. I hit this on an HP managed gigabit switch.  I tell the HP `set ip ssh key-length 1024` and it still doesn't work.  `debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 1032/2048
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.9.1.15 port 22: Invalid key length`  Using putty is my workaround as the economic and e-waste implications of throwing away a high-end gigabit switch for this are absurd. I betcha OpenSSH's hard line is convincing some people to switch back to telnet.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because of the remote or the local host key. Here are some workarounds for each case:

If the error is about YOUR host key you need to generate a new ssh-key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Or the older (no longer recommended) RSA key, but specifying the length:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa-sha2-512 -b 4096
```

If the error is the REMOTE host key you need to allow the exception (or fix the remote host) for this connection:

```
ssh -o RequiredRSASize=1024 ...the rest of your ssh command...
```

- Use *RSAMinSize=1024* for old openssh versions

If overriding the min. bit length doesn't work then most likely the remote host allows for a different algorithms, so you can find them and try them until you find one that works. (if you send an unsupported one it will return the valid ones)
Example:

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ...the rest of your ssh command...
```

Finally, once you find the settings that work you can optionally add the parameters to your ~/.ssh/config file. For example:

```
Host <the host>
    RequiredRSASize 1024
```

Sources:
https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openssh/c/aa843e85eeacfe9dc380cde93b9080bca0fe140f?branch=rawhide